# Seeking inventory of Mega Bloks set 9815

Tags: sets, clone-brands

I have [Mega Bloks set 9815](https://bricker.info/osets/MEGABLOKS/9815/). My children have lost the booklet that came with this set. I am looking for either in PDF or in Jpeg images a copy of the booklet. I hope to restore this set replacing missing pieces and to do this I need to know what was in this set.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  It looks like this was a bulk bricks/blocks bucket.  If you are missing a few pieces or have a few different pieces it changes things, but you still get to play with it.